# protocol for game server that has login(DB IO) service and realtime

Tags: c#, tcp, unity-game-engine, client-server, server

I'm new to client-server architecture and I'm quite confused with this.
I'm trying to make a game with unity that requires login and realtime.
For the gaming part, I was thinking TCP/IP protocol because it's a turn-base game.
But which one should I use for the login part?
Should I just sue TCP for login too? I think it would be too wasting to keep listening thread for the client with the login process.
I've only used HTTP connection for login process and it doesn't require thread because it immediately responses but I'm not sure if TCP protocol does that too.

I'm trying to program the whole thing in C# without using any frameworks or middlewares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to client-server architecture, I'd highly suggest you to use a unity package like [TNet](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=4518) even though that's not your original plan.

Network programming is a very difficult task and you'll save a lot of time using something that's already works just fine.